# Angular momentum conservation in a non-inertial frame

Tags: angular-momentum, reference-frames, rotational-dynamics, conservation-laws

> A uniform rod is kept on a horizontal, smooth surface. A point mass moving with some velocity strikes the end of the rod and sticks to the end. Will the angular momentum be conserved about the "geometric" center of the rod (which is not the same as the COM of the system)?

My initial thinking was that the angular momentum should remain conserved about all points in the plane, as there is no external torque acting on the "rod+mass" system.But the answer says angular momentum will not be conserved about the center.

The only sort of explanation I can come up for this is that the rod will accelerate due to the impact , and thus we are looking at a point in a non-inertial frame.

So is the external torque provided by the "pseudo-force" that we need to account for?

Comment: You must use the same frame to conserve angular momentum. You cannot use frame A (eg inertial frame) to calculate initial angular momentum and a different frame B (eg non intertial frame) for the final angular momentum.

Answer (score 0):

the moving mass has also a angular momentum relativ to the center, the sum of the two is conserved.

Comment: It is not, thats what the answer says, and thats what i attempted to explain.

Answer (score 0):

"The rate of change of angular momentum equals the applied torque" is only valid for torque and angular momentum  about certain points. These are: 1) the center of mass 2) A point at rest in an intertial frame 3) a point moving parallel to the centre of mass.  It follows from this that, in the absence of any torque, it is only angular momentum about these three types of points that is conserved.
The question is testing you on whether you have understood this.

Just work through the derivation of the torque/angular-momentum equation from $F=ma$ and you will see why the resrictions on the refernce point arise.

Comment: I just worked it out. The expression for rate of change of angular momentum about some point 'o' would contain both the velocity and the acceleration of  'o' , right? When both of the are zero, the expression collapses to  (moment of inertia about axis through o) * alpha. Right?